# How to use two different adapters on Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-volley

I'm trying to print in a listview the "contatos" array, and I'm trying to do that in another activity, the problem is,I've created another adapter just for it, but in this line of the code "ClientesContatosModel md = arrContatos.get(i);" it should get the "i" from the adapter that is in the ContatosView, How can I do that?

My Json:

```
{"total":3,"dados":[{"id":"9","id_rm_empresa":"2","id_rm_tipo_cliente":"1","tipo_pessoa":"PJ","cpf":null,"nome":"Apple","cnpj":null,"ie":null,"suframa":null,"ramo_de_atividade":null,"ano_de_fundacao":null,"informacoes_adicionais":null,"enderecos":[{"id_rm_endereco":"1","endereco":"Rua Rudolph Diesel","numero":"174","complemento":"","bairro":"Industrial","cep":"86063-330","cidade":"Londrina","estado":"Paran\u00e1","tipo_endereco":"Residencial"}],"contatos":[{"id_rm_cliente":"10","id_rm_contato":"1","id_rm_empresa":"2","nome":"Bill Gates","cargo":"Diretor","telefones":[{"id_rm_cliente":"10","id_rm_contato":"1","id_rm_telefone":"4","id_rm_empresa":"2","tipo":"Trabalho","numero":"(22) 2222-2222","criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2013-09-03 18:30:30","status":"A"},{"id_rm_cliente":"10","id_rm_contato":"1","id_rm_telefone":"9","id_rm_empresa":"2","tipo":"Celular","numero":"(44) 4444-4444","criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2013-09-03 18:30:30","status":"A"}],"emails":[{"id_rm_cliente":"10","id_rm_contato":"1","id_rm_email":"5","id_rm_empresa":"2","tipo":"Trabalho","email":"steve@apple-teste.com","criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2013-09-03 18:30:30","status":"A"}],"criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2013-09-03 18:30:30","status":"A"},{"id_rm_cliente":"10","id_rm_contato":"7","id_rm_empresa":"2","nome":"Linus Torvalds","cargo":"Diretor","telefones":[{"id_rm_cliente":"10","id_rm_contato":"1","id_rm_telefone":"4","id_rm_empresa":"2","tipo":"Trabalho","numero":"(22) 2222-2222","criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2013-09-03 18:30:30","status":"A"}],"emails":[{"id_rm_cliente":"10","id_rm_contato":"1","id_rm_email":"5","id_rm_empresa":"2","tipo":"Trabalho","email":"steve@apple-teste.com","criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2013-09-03 18:30:30","status":"A"}],"criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2013-09-03 18:30:30","status":"A"}],"telefones":[{"id_rm_empresa":"2","id_rm_cliente":"10","id_rm_telefone":"1","numero":"(43)3025-1355","tipo":"Casa","criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2013-09-03 18:30:30","status":"A"},{"id_rm_empresa":"2","id_rm_cliente":"10","id_rm_telefone":"2","numero":"(43)3000-6562","tipo":"Trabalho","criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2013-09-03 18:30:30","status":"A"}],"emails":[],"criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2012-09-04 18:30:34","status":"A"},{"id":"8","id_rm_empresa":"2","id_rm_tipo_cliente":"1","tipo_pessoa":"PJ","cpf":null,"nome":"Apple","cnpj":null,"ie":null,"suframa":null,"ramo_de_atividade":null,"ano_de_fundacao":null,"informacoes_adicionais":null,"enderecos":[{"id_rm_endereco":"1","endereco":"Rua Rudolph Diesel","numero":"174","complemento":"","bairro":"Industrial","cep":"86063-330","cidade":"Londrina","estado":"Paran\u00e1","tipo_endereco":"Residencial"}],"contatos":[{"id_rm_cliente":"10","id_rm_contato":"1","id_rm_empresa":"2","nome":"Bill Gates","cargo":"Diretor","telefones":[{"id_rm_cliente":"10","id_rm_contato":"1","id_rm_telefone":"4","id_rm_empresa":"2","tipo":"Trabalho","numero":"(22) 2222-2222","criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2013-09-03 18:30:30","status":"A"},{"id_rm_cliente":"10","id_rm_contato":"1","id_rm_telefone":"9","id_rm_empresa":"2","tipo":"Celular","numero":"(44) 4444-4444","criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2013-09-03 18:30:30","status":"A"}],"emails":[{"id_rm_cliente":"10","id_rm_contato":"1","id_rm_email":"5","id_rm_empresa":"2","tipo":"Trabalho","email":"steve@apple-teste.com","criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2013-09-03 18:30:30","status":"A"}],"criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2013-09-03 18:30:30","status":"A"},{"id_rm_cliente":"10","id_rm_contato":"7","id_rm_empresa":"2","nome":"Linus Torvalds","cargo":"Diretor","telefones":[{"id_rm_cliente":"10","id_rm_contato":"1","id_rm_telefone":"4","id_rm_empresa":"2","tipo":"Trabalho","numero":"(22) 2222-2222","criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2013-09-03 18:30:30","status":"A"}],"emails":[{"id_rm_cliente":"10","id_rm_contato":"1","id_rm_email":"5","id_rm_empresa":"2","tipo":"Trabalho","email":"steve@apple-teste.com","criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2013-09-03 18:30:30","status":"A"}],"criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2013-09-03 18:30:30","status":"A"}],"telefones":[{"id_rm_empresa":"2","id_rm_cliente":"10","id_rm_telefone":"1","numero":"(43)3025-1355","tipo":"Casa","criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2013-09-03 18:30:30","status":"A"},{"id_rm_empresa":"2","id_rm_cliente":"10","id_rm_telefone":"2","numero":"(43)3000-6562","tipo":"Trabalho","criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2013-09-03 18:30:30","status":"A"}],"emails":[],"criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2012-09-04 18:30:34","status":"A"},{"id":"10","id_rm_empresa":"2","id_rm_tipo_cliente":"1","tipo_pessoa":"PJ","cpf":null,"nome":"Webee","cnpj":null,"ie":null,"suframa":null,"ramo_de_atividade":null,"ano_de_fundacao":null,"informacoes_adicionais":null,"enderecos":[{"id_rm_endereco":"1","endereco":"Rua Rudolph Diesel","numero":"174","complemento":"","bairro":"Industrial","cep":"86063-330","cidade":"Londrina","estado":"Paran\u00e1","tipo_endereco":"Residencial"}],"contatos":[{"id_rm_cliente":"10","id_rm_contato":"1","id_rm_empresa":"2","nome":"Steve Jobs","cargo":"Diretor","telefones":{"total":1,"dados":[{"id_rm_cliente":"10","id_rm_contato":"1","id_rm_telefone":"4","id_rm_empresa":"2","tipo":"Trabalho","numero":"(22) 2222-2222","criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2013-09-03 18:30:30","status":"A"}]},"emails":{"total":1,"dados":[{"id_rm_cliente":"10","id_rm_contato":"1","id_rm_email":"5","id_rm_empresa":"2","tipo":"Trabalho","email":"steve@apple-teste.com","criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2013-09-03 18:30:30","status":"A"}]},"criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2013-09-03 18:30:30","status":"A"}],"telefones":[{"id_rm_empresa":"2","id_rm_cliente":"10","id_rm_telefone":"1","numero":"(43)3025-1355","tipo":"Casa","criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2013-09-03 18:30:30","status":"A"},{"id_rm_empresa":"2","id_rm_cliente":"10","id_rm_telefone":"2","numero":"(43)3000-6562","tipo":"Trabalho","criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2013-09-03 18:30:30","status":"A"}],"emails":[],"criado":"2013-09-01 07:00:00","modificado":"2013-09-03 18:30:30","status":"A"}]}
```

Json parsed:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    private ListView lstView;

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ArrayList<ClientesModel> arrNews ;
    public ArrayList<ClientesContatosModel> arrContatos ;
    public LayoutInflater lf;
    private VolleyAdapter va;
    private ProgressDialog pd;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lf = LayoutInflater.from(this);       
        arrNews = new ArrayList<ClientesModel>();
        arrContatos = new ArrayList<ClientesContatosModel>();
        va = new VolleyAdapter();    
        lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);    
        lstView.setAdapter(va);
        mRequestQueue =  Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "http://192.168.1.1/represente-api/api/clientes/index.php";
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please Wait...","Please Wait...");          
                   JsonObjectRequest jr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {           
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.i(TAG,response.toString());
                try {
                    parseJson(response);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                va.notifyDataSetChanged();
                pd.dismiss();
                ;            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                error.printStackTrace();
                pd.hide();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError{
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email", "rm@.com.br");
                params.put("senha", "xxxx");       
                return params;
            }    
            };
        mRequestQueue.add(jr);        
        }    

    private void parseJson(JSONObject json) throws JSONException{
        try{        
                JSONArray dados = json.getJSONArray("dados");
                for(int i=0;i<dados.length();i++) {
                JSONObject item = dados.getJSONObject(i);       
                ClientesModel mClientesModel = new ClientesModel();
                ClientesContatosModel mClientesContatoModel = new ClientesContatosModel();    
                /* cadastra os dados necessários no objeto no modelo */
                mClientesModel.setId(item.optInt("id"));
                mClientesModel.setNome(item.optString("nome"));
                mClientesModel.setTipo_pessoa(item.optString("tipo_pessoa"));                    mClientesModel.setInformacoes_adicionais(item.optString("informacoes_adicionais"));
                mClientesModel.setCpf(item.optString("cpf"));
                mClientesModel.setCnpj(item.optString("cnpj"));
                JSONArray contatos = item.getJSONArray("contatos");
                for(int j=0;j<contatos.length();j++){
                    JSONObject data = contatos.getJSONObject(j);    
                    mClientesContatoModel.setNome(data.optString("nome"));    
                    mClientesContatoModel.setCargo(data.optString("cargo"));    
                }    
                arrNews.add(mClientesModel);
                arrContatos.add(mClientesContatoModel);
            }        
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }              
    }

       public class VolleyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arrNews.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return arrNews.get(i);

        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            final ViewHolder vh ;
            if(view == null){
                vh = new ViewHolder();
                view = lf.inflate(R.layout.row_listview,null);
                vh.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
                vh.tvDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);
                vh.tvInfo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
                vh.tvContato = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNome);       
                view.setTag(vh);
            }
            else{
                vh = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            ClientesModel nm = arrNews.get(i);
            vh.tvTitle.setText(nm.getNome());
            vh.tvDesc.setText(nm.getTipo_pessoa());
            vh.tvInfo.setText(nm.getInformacoes_adicionais());           
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ClientesContatosModel md = arrContatos.get(i);
                        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            ContatosView.class);
                            in.putExtra("cargo", md.getNome());
                            startActivity(in);        
                }
            });                
            return view;
            }

      public  class  ViewHolder{
            TextView tvTitle;
            TextView tvDesc;
            TextView tvInfo;
            TextView tvContato;

        }

    }
}
```

IntentClass:

```
public class ContatosView extends MainActivity {
    public  VolleyAdapter vb;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contatos_view);
            Intent in = getIntent();
            // Get JSON values from previous intent
        String name = in.getStringExtra("cargo");
                // Displaying all values on the screen
        TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
            vb = new VolleyAdapter();
        lblName.setText(name);

    }

    public class VolleyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
            @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arrContatos.size();
        }
            @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return arrContatos.get(i);

        }
            @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            final ViewHolder vh ;
            if(view == null){
                vh = new ViewHolder();
                view = lf.inflate(R.layout.contatos_view,null);
                vh.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
                vh.tvCargo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtCargo);


                view.setTag(vh);
            }
            else{
                vh = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            ClientesContatosModel md = arrContatos.get(i);
            vh.tvTitle.setText(md.getNome());
            vh.tvCargo.setText(md.getCargo());
            return view;

        }

        public  class  ViewHolder{
            TextView tvTitle;
            TextView tvCargo;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: There are many errors in your code. In first activity your passing "cargo" in intent & in second activity you are using "nome". Always check your code before posting question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I've just edited that part of the code

Comment: Instead of taking "VolleyAdapter" as an inner class in both activities. You can take it seperately & call same "VolleyAdapter" from both activities & set it to your listviews in both activities. & the fields you don't want in second activity just set them invisible.

Comment: @RIT Can you guide me on how would I do that? I'm new to android development, if you could I'd appreciate that.

Comment: First of all you need to go custom listview tutorials. Google for custom listview then you'll get to know how to do functionality of above comment.